# mysqldump collation issues

Tags: mysql, backup, collation, utf-8

I have tried my hand at building a shell script to backup our wordpress database using tar balls and chron jobs on a Debian environment.
The problem I am facing now is that our wp database after exporting, using the script, and then importing, using phpmyadmin, loses some special characters. Most noteably the `€` sign.
Phpmyadmin lists the database as `latin1_swedish_ci` and that is the collation setting I am selecting in the Import tab of phpmyadmin (iso-8859-1).
I am using the following script to export the database:

> mysqldump --user=user --password=password --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset databasename -r wp-db.sql
>
> > tar -cpzf /home/backups/wp-backups/website-wp-$(date +"%d-%m-%Y--%H-%M").tar.gz wp-db.sql && rm wp-db.sql

My best guess is that there must be some issue with collation but I am not aware where some type of conversion happens in the steps that I am taking. At some point the `€` must be dropped.
When inspecting the `wp-db.sql` using `file` it is described as `iso-8859-1`, hence I wonder where conversion takes place.
I have since tried to test some things and discovered that I am not capable of converting a `UTF-8`file to `iso-8859-1`if it includes a `€` sign. At least not using

> iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO_8859-1 test

From what I gather mysql runs in `UTF-8` natively, might that be the issue?

If I do not bother with any of this it will completely ruin things. Pretty much everything that isnt wp files but stored in the database will be displayed incorrectly or will be completely missing. By adding these two arguments to my script I have eliminated most of the issues apart from special character problems.

Comment: If you don't bother with charactersets and just do the export then import without even mentioning them, does it work? Just a bit worried you're trying to over complicate things

Comment: That is a good point. I have been working on this way too much to look at it from an outsider's perspective. Yes, it was needed. Before I even looked  into the entire collation thing the backups were able to be imported but utterly unworkable (as desribed in my edit to OP).

Answer (score -1):

"displayed incorrectly" -- That does *not* necessarily mean that the text is *stored* incorrectly.  How many steps do you have here?

You have data in a WP database?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one of the tables so we can verify whether it is latin1 or utf8.  Also, do `SELECT col, HEX(col)` to see what you have in the table for `€`.  For utf8, the hex should be `E282AC`.  As you pointed out, it cannot be stored in latin1.  If you don't see that hex, *stop*; we need to debug things *before* this point.  Else continue...

Then you are doing a dump?  Let mysqldump specify the `CHARACTER SET` (not `COLLATION`).

Take a peek at the dump file.  Well, this may be useless, because it depends on what tool you use to peek at it.

Then you are reloading the data?  After reloading, what does the hex say?  Again, *stop* if it is not that same hex.

Now you are running WP and trying to display stuff.  On a web page?  Look at the HTML; there should be a `<meta... >` tag very near the start.  What does it say?  In particular, does it say `charset=UTF-8`?

One more thing to check is the `SET NAMES utf8` (or equivalent) -- phpmyadmin establishes the `CHARACTER SET` one place; find it.  And find it for WP.

Comment: Okay. A lot of things for me to figure out first. I will look into this and get back to you. Thank you very much for the input.

Comment: I have never really worked with mysql before so some of the things you said took me a while to understand. The issue is that my "web guy" cant tell me what table contains the `€` sign so it was not possible for me to hunt it down. I have made a new, utf8_unicode_ci, DB and imported my current DB as latin1. I had to have him readd some of the data but now we can reliably export and reimport without loosing data. Not sure what caused any of this in the first place but latin1 was not the correct collation to work with. Thanks for your helpful input.

Comment: Apparently you did not have the settings correct when moving from latin1 to utf8.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score -1):

Go to Status and System Variables in MySQL Workbench

I set all UTF8 to UTF8MB4
Don't change binary, etc...

[MySQL Workbench Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DflA8G5OCtQ) - Check default character set Collation of MySQL Server by using Workbench